# In iOS image from SOAP service set as NSData is cut. Which can be the reason?

Tags: ios, soap, nsdata, nsimage

I have SOAP service. I use [sudzc.com](http://sudzc.com/) generated wrapper to access the service. During the communication I receive an image (several different images) which I have to expose. I use NSData field saved in .plist file to store the image. My problem is that in some cases The image is cut on the right side. I use `Aspect fit`. I am almost sure that the image is cut inside my App, because we have similar App on `Android` and in that App image is ok. Also I use `Right` and the right side is also cut.

Any ideas how to manage that situation?

**EDIT:**

I tried with fixed image (as [poojathorat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2542103/poojathorat) suggested). The fixed image was shown ok.

I remove all constraints and widen the area of the image in the IB but it is still cut (even it is resized - the sizes of the parts of the image are bigger).

Comment: is your imageview is in scrollview ? Maybe you have not properly setted the constraints for an imageview.Try with attaching any harcoded image.

Comment: No,  @poojathorat, it is not in Scroll View. It is in the middle of the page. This idea with hardcoded image is good. I will try it right now.

Comment: Fixed image is visualised properly without cutting any part, @poojathorat.

Answer (score 0):

Set the content mode of image as scaleToFill.

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Sorry, @swapnali patil, but this is not working. May be the data is not saved correctly when extracting from SOAP service?

Comment: you can check you are getting correct image or not by this UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
[yourImageView setImage:img];